# How to get warned if JavaScript's window "namespace" becomes polluted?

Tags: javascript, namespaces

The context is JavaScript. I've just been tracking down two errors that were difficult to find.

In one case, there was written

```
for (var k in items) {
  item = items[k]
```

... so the missing `var` before `item` caused `window`'s `item()` method to be mangled.

In the other case, there was written

```
parent = this.parentOfRow(row);
```

... and the missing `var` before `parent` caused a mess with the `window`'s `parent` member.

Both errors became visible many steps away.

Does somebody now a good way to get warned by some kind of "surveillance tool"?

Answer (score 1):

I think a good first course of action is to `"use strict"`, which [enables strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode). This will cause missing `var`'s to throw errors:

```js
'use strict';
var items = { a: 'b', c: 'd' };

for (var k in items) {
  item = items[k]
}
```

Comment: Very good. I've just tried to switch it on and found immediately two more variables without `var`. Thank you. Do you know of any unexpected drawbacks?

Comment: I only know of expected drawbacks when working with 'use strict' - namely the part where erroneous code that used to work now throws an error :-)

Comment: :-)) Yes, I see. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK JShint (http://jshint.com/) will warn you whenever you imply an implicit global variable by leaving off the var keyword.

```
    function main() {
        myVariable = 15;
        return myVariable;
    }

   main();
```

This will throw a JS hint error, informing you that myVariable is undefined. Being mindful of these errors prevents you polluting the global namespace.

Comment: Thank you, this looks like a valuable tool to use in projects.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Rob's suggestion, you should **look into linting tools** like [ESLint](http://eslint.org/).

These will warn you about a lot of common pitfalls and help you avoid issues that you may have missed otherwise.

Relevant ESLint rules for your case would probably be

- [no-implicit-globals](http://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-implicit-globals)
- [no-undef](http://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-undef)

Comment: Thank you. This goes towards static code analysis, that'll be helpful.